# Disable Windowsauthentication WCF

Tags: wcf, web-services, security, windows-authentication

I'm using WCF to create a Client-Server Application and I'm having some problems with authentication, with wsHttpBinding Windowsauthentication seems to be turned on by default. The webservice worked perfectly inside my network but when I installed it somewhere else I suddenly had all these securityexceptions.

Though I want the webservice to be encrypted with https, i dont want windows authentication.

Although I can't try it at the moment I've found this Configuration:

```
<security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
```

Which might do the trick. This is my "old" one:

```
<security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
```

This is the configuration on the client side which i dont quite understand cause anybody could just change this easily. I'd expect to configure this on the server side but i havent yet found out how.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it through IIS Authentication settings for the site hosting your WCF by turning it off there and leaving anonymous on.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Yeah but is it still encrypted then?